# How to check if process is still running before calling Process.GetProcessById?

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics

In .NET [`Process.GetProcessById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76fkb36k.aspx) throws an exception if the process with this ID is not running. How to safely call this method so that it won't throw an exception? I am thinking something like

```
if(Process.IsRunning(id)) return Process.GetProcessById(id);
else return null; //or do something else
```

But can't find any method to check the ID, other than probably getting all the running processes and check whether the id exist in the list.

Comment: Is it bad if you caught the exception?

Comment: In my experience and testing, the performance of coding by exception like that is very bad

Comment: So it is about performance?? Well, if you just surround these two lines with try-catch it wouldn't hurt, I believe...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
public Process GetProcByID(int id)
{
    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
    return processlist.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.Id == id);
}
```

I looked inside `Process.GetProcessById` method.

It uses internal static class ProcessManager to ensure, that process runs.
ProcessManager gets all the processes currently running in system and checks there ids, so I think it is the best way to do it.

So you should consider the overhead of exception or the overhead of `Process` array.

Answer (score 3):

Just use try-catch block

```
Process p = null;
try{
  p = Process.GetProcessById(id);
}
catch(Exception){

}
return p;
```

Answer (score 2):

Same code using pinvoke, this should be faster as GetProcesses, as it does not require all processes enumeration.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags access, bool inheritHandle, int procId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetExitCodeProcess(IntPtr hProcess, out uint lpExitCode);

[Flags]
public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
{
    All = 0x001F0FFF,
    Terminate = 0x00000001,
    CreateThread = 0x00000002,
    VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
    VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
    VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
    DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
    CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
    SetQuota = 0x00000100,
    SetInformation = 0x00000200,
    QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
    QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
    Synchronize = 0x00100000
}


/// <summary>
/// Checks if given process is still alive
/// </summary>
/// <param name="processId">process id</param>
/// <returns>true if process is alive, false if not</returns>
static public bool IsProcessAlive(int processId)
{
    IntPtr h = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation, true, processId);

    if (h == IntPtr.Zero)
        return false;

    uint code = 0;
    bool b = GetExitCodeProcess(h, out code);
    CloseHandle(h);

    if (b)
        b = (code == 259) /* STILL_ACTIVE  */;

    return b;
}
```

Comment: This is faster and does not throw any exception. Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, using try + catch will probably do the trick. If the process is not running, nothing will happen instead of throwing an exception.